# Confusion about environmental variables in python

Tags: python, environment-variables

I'm having a bit of trouble figuring out the use of environmental variables in a bit of sample code from one of the MIT 6.006 'Intro to algorithms' course.

I just finished problem set 3, and when looking through the solutions (found [here](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-006-introduction-to-algorithms-fall-2011/assignments/)), the code uses this sort of syntax to change variable names:

```
if sys.version_info >= (3,):
    xrange = range
```

this makes perfect sense since in python 3, range == xrange

however, later in the solution block, they end up defining different classes to overwrite existing classes. The details aren't too important here, but essentially when they do so, they put in an 'if' statement to change one Class implementation to another. For example, they create an array-based range index "BlitRangeIndex" to overwrite "RangeIndex":

```
if os.environ.get('INDEX') == 'blit':
  RangeIndex = BlitRangeIndex
```

However, I don't understand how the variable "INDEX" was ever put into the environmental variables. There is no indication in the code that this ever happened, so I don't understand how the 'if' statement is evaluated as true.

Any insight would be great! I'm still learning a lot about the inner workings of python, and I just can't seem to figure this one out.

Comment: as far as I know they would have to add INDEX to an environment before running the program, and then they can define whatever they want - i.e. `export INDEX=blit`...

Comment: The environmet can be set *before* the program even starts (either manually or by some parent process), the program can simply find it in there.

Comment: If environment variable INDEX has not been set the if statement evaluates to false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It just assumes that you have set environment variables before running the program.
For example, in a Linux environment you would do something like this:

```
$ export INDEX=value 
$ export CROSS=value 
$ export TRACE=value
$ python path/to/full_circuit2.py
```

However, if you prefer, you can override these vaiaveis by constants, like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

INDEX='value'
CROSS='value' 
TRACE='value'

...
```

You can even pass values by command line arguments:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys  
# other imports... 

INDEX = sys.argv[1]
CROSS = sys.argv[2]
TRACE = sys.argv[3]

...

if INDEX == 'blit': # instead if os.environ.get('INDEX')
  RangeIndex = BlitRangeIndex

...
```

Comment: alternatively env INDEX=blit pythonfull_circuit2.py